# Disable Page Cache for NFS protocol

Tags: linux, nfs, disk, cache

I have an NFS client that perform READ FILE operations from a shared NFS server.
On the server, I monitor FILE READ operations.
The problem is when I read the same file (with different users) on the same machine - it will only invoke 1 READ FILE operation via NFS Protocol (on client and therefor on server).

After investigation ([this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/831387/disable-all-nfs-client-cache-on-centos/831809?noredirect=1#comment1062672_831809)) - I have discovered that when cleaning the page cache:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

READ FILE operation will be invoked again.

Is it possible to enforce the kernel/OS to disable page caching for NFS protocol ?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible. Imagine what would happen if you tried to execute a file from an NFS server. The file gets mapped into memory, but not actually read into memory because using the page cache is not allowed. The program begins to execute but page faults immediately because the memory mapping is not cached in RAM. Non starter. Okay, so let's say we are allowed to relax the rule a little bit and fill the page cache for just this page for just this once. We read it into RAM from the NFS server and resolve the page fault but then promptly evict it. The program executes one instruction — maybe — and then page faults again.

You could make it work a little less ridiculously than the thought experiment I just described, especially it you are talking about normal `read()` and not `mmap()`, but your solution would still be completely at odds with how virtual memory works fundamentally and would perform very badly.

Comment: So how come when i "cat" the same file locally in the linux bash, i get 2 file read operation on the kernel vfs layer. I does not cache local filesystem sych as ext3/4?

Comment: Are you saying that you `cat` the file once and this results in 2 vfs read operations? I guess that depends on the detail of what `cat` is doing and the size of the file (whether `cat` is reading it in multiple chunks, etc...).